# How I can link the output of the 1st program as an input for the 2nd program using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program written in Python and need to use the output values of this program as an input values to my second program of same python folder. May I know is it possible to do; if so can you please tell me which module is used and would be great if I can get a small example.

For example below is the first program and from this how I can take the output value 'x' to plot in my second program.

```
from functools import partial

import numpy
import scipy.optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp

def z(x, y):
    return  x * y - 30

x_window = 0, 15
y_window = 0, 5

xs = []
ys = []
for x in numpy.linspace(*x_window, num=200):
    try:
        # A more efficient technique would use the last-found-y-value as a 
        # starting point
        y = scipy.optimize.brentq(partial(z, x), *y_window)
    except ValueError:
        # Should we not be able to find a solution in this window.
        pass
    else:
        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)

pp.plot(xs, ys)
pp.xlim(*x_window)
pp.ylim(*y_window)
pp.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Rearrange your code and put everything in functions:

```
# file my_program.py

from functools import partial

import numpy
import scipy.optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp

def z(x, y):
    return  x * y - 30

def make_data(x_window, y_window):


    xs = []
    ys = []
    for x in numpy.linspace(*x_window, num=200):
        try:
            # A more efficient technique would use the last-found-y-value as a 
            # starting point
            y = scipy.optimize.brentq(partial(z, x), *y_window)
        except ValueError:
            # Should we not be able to find a solution in this window.
            pass
        else:
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)
    return xs, ys

def plot(xs, ys, x_window, y_window):         
    pp.plot(xs, ys)
    pp.xlim(*x_window)
    pp.ylim(*y_window)
    pp.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x_window = 0, 15
    y_window = 0, 5
    xs, ys = make_data(x_window, y_window)
    plot(xs, ys, x_window, y_window)
```

Now, in your second file, you can import it from the same folder and call `make_data()`:

```
import my_program


x_window = 0, 15
y_window = 0, 5
xs, ys = my_program.make_data(x_window, y_window)
```

Answer (score 0):

In e.g. bash, or even the windows command prompt, you can just pipe'em:

```
> python prog1.py | python prog2.py
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first program return the value needed and save it in a text file and in the second program open the file and use the value from the imported file as an input to your second program.